# Django Jquery Autofill data from models

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui-autocomplete, autofill

i want make autofill form like this :

[image]
http://www.tutorialspark.com/jqueryUI/jQuery_UI_AutoComplete_Overridding_Default_Select_Action.php

what i already know is to get list of cities form models :

views.py

```
def autofill(request):
if 'term' in request.GET:
    qs = City.objects.filter(cities__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
    citys = list()
    
    citys = [city.cities for city in qs]
    return JsonResponse(citys, safe=False)
    
return render(request, 'part/test.html',)
```

jquery :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        var zipCode = { Chicago: 60290, California: 90001, Chennai: 600040, 
                        Cambridge:02138 , Colombo:00800 };
        
        $('#autoSuggest').autocomplete({
            source: "{% url 'autofill' %}",
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#zipCode').val(zipCode[ui.item.value]);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Models.py

```
class City(models.Model):
 cities = models.CharField(max_length=120)
 zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=120)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.cities
```

while i still don't understand how to get zipCode data from models, and pair it with city ?
Thanks

Comment: Show your `models.py` file too

Answer (score 1):

**You can use AJAX with Django to fetch city and zipcode without refresh the page like this :**

```
"""your vieww.py that return a JSON response to the frontend"""
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import City

def city_zipcode(request):
    """Retrieve all cities objects and return only cities and zipcode"""
    cities = City.objects.values('cities', 'zipcode')
    """Here w'll have an object like <QuerySet [{'cities': 'Chicago', 'zipcode': 60290}, ... ]>"""

    # Transform this queryset to dict with cities and zipcode as Key/Pair

    data_dict = {}
    for dict in cities:
        data_dict[dict['cities']] = dict['zipcode']
        
    """Here data_dict = {'Chicago': 60290, ...}"""
    
    return JsonResponse(data_dict)


# urls.py
path('city_zipcode/', views.city_zipcode, name='city_zipcode'),

// javascript, this is in the template file (add this before the close body tag)
{% block javascript %}
<script>
    async function getCities() {
        // Django like url in JS
        let url = '{% url 'city_zipcode' %}';
        try {
            // Get the backend JSON result
            let results = await fetch(url);
            return await results.json();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    
    // Call the function to get the cities paired with zipcode
    let zipCode = await getCities();

    // Here you can run your jQuery code
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        // Use zipCode variable here, you can try to convert it to
       // javascript dict before use it :
       zipCode = JSON.parse(zipCode);  // A javaScript object
    });

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Answer (score 1):

The other answer works too, but here's a method to do it without loading all zipcodes in memory, only the one that you need:

###### views.py

```
def get_zipcode(request, city_name):
    city = get_object_or_404(City, cities=city_name)
    return JsonResponse({zipcode: city.zipcode}, safe=False)
```

###### urls.py

```
path('get_zipcode/<str:city_name>/', get_zipcode, name='get_zipcode'),
```

###### js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#autoSuggest').autocomplete({
            source: "{% url 'autofill' %}",
            select: async function(event, ui) {
                let resp = await fetch(`/get_zipcode/${ui.item.value}/`);
                let json = await resp.json()
                $('#zipCode').val(json.zipcode);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi, when i try this i got error unknown zipcode from Return JsonResponse line